# error : while expected /eached end of file while parsing

Tags: java, android

galera eu estou tento problemas com meu app de Bingo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int[] ids = {R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7,
            R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.button10, R.id.button11, R.id.button12, R.id.button13, R.id.button14,
            R.id.button15, R.id.button16, R.id.button17, R.id.button18, R.id.button19, R.id.button20, R.id.button21,
            R.id.button22, R.id.button23, R.id.button24, R.id.button25, R.id.button26};
    int cont = 0;
    int[] vetaux = new int[25];
    boolean isRepetido = false;
    Random sorteador = new Random();
    int n1 = 0;
    boolean y = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        do {
            n1 = sorteador.nextInt(100);
            for (int cont1 = 0; cont1 < cont; cont1++) {
                if (vetaux[cont1] == n1) {
                    y = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    y = false;
                }
            }
            if (y == false) {
                vetaux[cont] = n1;
                cont++;
            }
            while (cont < 25) ;
            {
            //int Nsorteado = sorteador.nextInt(100);//Nsorteado armzenou o numero
            for (int cont = 0; cont < ids.length; cont++) {
                int Id = ids[cont];
                int n1 = vetaux[cont];
                String txt1 = String.valueOf(n1);
                Button button = (Button) findViewById(Id);
                button.setText(txt1);
            }

        }
    } 
}
```

> error : while expected
>   error :reached end of file while parsing

Comment: aconselho que leia um pouco sobre https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, e tambem de agradecimento a usuários que estão utilizando certo tempo para ajudar em suas questões.

Comment: na frente do seu while tem um ponto e virgula remova-o e veja se funciona

Comment: @EzequielMessore se ele remover o ; onde saberá o fim do "do...while" ??

Comment: @Matheus o escopo do while é delimitado pelas chaves exemplo:

    while(i<10){

    }

vc nao preciso do ponto e virgula para saber onde é o fim

Comment: Sim do while sim, mas ele está utilizando um do..while que tambem é utilizado chaves, mas as chaves acontecem antes de chamar o while

Comment: @Matheus me ignore por favor agora que notei que é um do/while ...

Comment: galara...problema resolvido ...o problema estava em fechar em

Comment: do{
}while;{
}
obrigado a todos...sou novo aqui e gostaria de saber como faço para agradecer aos usuarios que me ajudaram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você abriu chaves após realizar um do while, como se fosse um while normal, tente isso, remova aquele `{` único que está depois do seu `while`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int[] ids = {R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7,
        R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.button10, R.id.button11, R.id.button12, R.id.button13, R.id.button14,
        R.id.button15, R.id.button16, R.id.button17, R.id.button18, R.id.button19, R.id.button20, R.id.button21,
        R.id.button22, R.id.button23, R.id.button24, R.id.button25, R.id.button26};
int cont = 0;
int[] vetaux = new int[25];
boolean isRepetido = false;
Random sorteador = new Random();
int n1 = 0;
boolean y = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    do {
        n1 = sorteador.nextInt(100);
        for (int cont1 = 0; cont1 < cont; cont1++) {
            if (vetaux[cont1] == n1) {
                y = true;
                break;
            } else {
                y = false;
            }
        }
        if (y == false) {
            vetaux[cont] = n1;
            cont++;
        }
        while (cont < 25) ;
        //int Nsorteado = sorteador.nextInt(100);//Nsorteado armzenou o numero
        for (int cont = 0; cont < ids.length; cont++) {
            int Id = ids[cont];
            int n1 = vetaux[cont];
            String txt1 = String.valueOf(n1);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(Id);
            button.setText(txt1);
        }

    }
} 


}
```

Comment: tentei, porem sem sucesso...

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro ?

Comment: sim ...continua while expected.... e reached end of file while parsing

Comment: Então o erro deve estar em outra parte do seu código, pois este erro acontece por excesso ou falta de chaves no código

Comment: @EzequielMessore não importa onde tem que ficar o for dele, o erro dele é apenas um erro de sintaxe da linguagem, ele está esquecendo de adicionar ou remover as chaves...